# Expectation of maximum over an infinite sequence of sub-Guassian random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

It's a problem from 'High Dimensional Statistics' (MIT's lecture notes)

(Problem 1.3,page30)Let $X_1,X_2$ ... be an infinite sequence of sub-Guassian random variables with variance proxy $\sigma_{i}^{2}=C(\log i)^{-1/2}$. Show that for C large enough, we get:

$$
E[\max_{i\geq2}X_i]< \infty
$$
QU:

I find it a bit counter-intuition because I feel when C is larger, the expectation will be larger and more likely to get $\infty$ since the tail is thicker. But if I didn't misunderstand it, the problem says 'We need a C large enough to get a finite expectation'. Or it just says the expectation will be finite no matter how large the C is? Under both interpretations, I fail to prove it. :(

Ps: Definition: A random variable X is said to be *sub-Guassian* with variance proxy $\sigma^2$ if $E[X]=0$ and its moment generating function satisfies:
$$
E[\exp(sX)]\leq \exp(\dfrac{\sigma^2s^2}{2}), \forall s\in R
$$
It's just an extension to guassian's.

Comment: Yeah I agree that it is counter intuitive.  I would also read it is "for the expectation to be finite $C$ would need to be large enough". Also are you sure that the variance proxy is proportional to $(\log i)^{-1/2}$? I believe it should be proportional to $(\log i)^{-1-\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon > 0$ to ensure that the expectation is finite.

Comment: Thxs for your help! Yes,$\sigma_i^2=C(logi)^{-1/2}$ I just copied it from the book.(Though I can't gurantee the book is right...).  But a proof under the condition that 'with variance proxy proportional to $(logi)^{−1−ϵ}$ for $ϵ>0$ will be also helpful for me! I can also put some possibly related Theorems in book if needed.